# Is this a good way to structure header importing

Tags: ios

I am building an app, where I have made a Menu class which is a tableview being presented to the user (containing link to different view controllers, which should be presented on click).
Instead of importing any viewc. header in either of my viewc.'s I decided to import all the view controllers headers into my Menu.h. This way I can make all app navigation from menu class. I will then import menu.h in my appDelegate.h and then import only appDelegate.h to all my view controllers. Are there any unforeseen downsides to this, or should I do it another way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it compiles then that's OK, however it's considered best to use *forward declarations* in header files where ever possible to improve compile time.

Any custom type can be forward declared in the header file, of the using class, with:

```
@class YourViewController;
```

and then within the implementation file of the using class, include the actual header file:

```
#import "YourViewController.h"
```

Using *forward declaration* can also stop *dependency loops* where `A.h` includes `B.h`, which itself includes `A.h`.

Comment: I understand the dependence loop is bad, but is it not right to include menu.h in all view controllers. I mean, that makes sense since all vc's but one need the menu. Making forward declarations to all other view controllers but the one that is the current seems tidious and much more messy. but ye, it won't have the self-importing problem. Sorry if I'm being unclear

Answer (score 0):

Doing this you will have a include loop (which is bad !).

`Menu.h` is importing `ViewController1.h`

`AppDelegate.h` is importing `Menu.h` (and `ViewController1.h`)

`ViewController1.h` is importing `AppDelegate.h` (and `Menu.h` (and `ViewController1.h`))

A clean solution is to use Forward declaration when needed, and doing your import in .m files